# Find what is causing this event "handle_wpfs_event" to be triggered on the site

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments, wordpress-rest-api

I am having trouble with a particular site of mine, that is using Stripe plugin (particularly this plugin - Accept Stripe Payments by Tips and Tricks HQ, wptipsntricks).

The problem consists of - CPU seconds for the month have been exhausted due to a single site that I have exceeding the CPU usage to the above plugin.

1. I have already removed the plugin completely but the issue is still in place.

I was told by SiteGround hosting the following - the issue is relating thousands of POST requests made towards your site's admin-post.php script. They are all coming from 54.187.205.235. They look like so:[issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2f8Y.jpg). So it is perhaps some kind of a stripe API.

I have removed everything on the website relating to Stripe including woocommerce, stripe payment plugin but it is still calling to the site. I do not know what else to do.

Any help would be absolutely appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your time. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

54.187.205.235 is one of Stripe Webhook IP ([listed in their Doc](https://stripe.com/docs/ips#webhook-notifications)). It means you have configured your Stripe Account to have [a webhook endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks), and whenever an action occurred on your account, Stripe will send a webhook event to your site.

You would want to login into your Stripe Account and remove that webhook endpoint completely. If you are unsure about your Stripe account, reach out to Stripe Support.